# Command to change Mode Preference in Android O (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

The command to change UE mode preference that seemed to work on Nougat & Marshmallow isn't working for Android O (Oreo). Does anyone know the correct command?

I tried the old commands:

```
adb root && wait-for-device
adb remount && timeout 3
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 11
adb shell sync
adb reboot
timeout 5
exit
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the commands are the same but there is a small change.
Mode Pref needs to know which SUB ID is the active SUB in order to change the UE mode preference.

So the command:

```
adb logcat -b radio |grep -I subid
```

would indicate the current SUB ID.
Once you find out the SUB, then the command to change mode pref is :

```
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode3 11
```

where _mode**3** was the active SUB in my case.